# check if a fuse is good or bad in an ac circuit using arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics, electricity, fuses

I have a fuse in a ac circuit of which i want to check if the fuse is ok or not. I'm wishing to wire up two nodes of the fuse holder and determine the fuse status. I have a plan of notify user if the fuse is ok or not.

How can I do that using arduino?

Comment: AC and what is the voltage?

Comment: Bluntly, **don't do that**.  The serious challenges of doing so *safely* are far beyond the scope of the Arduino site.  At best, there might be some *existing* property of the powered equipment which you could non-invasively monitor, for example, gluing a light sensor to the *exterior* of the enclosure over an existing power light.  **Do not** attempt to make any connections from an Arduino to mains circuitry.

Comment: @MatsK 220V. I'm wishing to check the fuse of an IPS.

Comment: easy: just use a hall-effect current sensor; if the fuse is ok, there will be current.